# why am i losing data when going from double to decimal

Tags: c#

I have the following code which I can't change...

```
 public static decimal Convert(decimal value, Measurement currentMeasurement, Measurement targetMeasurement,  bool roundResult = true)
 {
     double result = Convert(System.Convert.ToDouble(value), currentMeasurement, targetMeasurement, roundResult);
     return System.Convert.ToDecimal(result);
 }
```

now `result` is returned as `-23.333333333333336` but once the conversion to a `decimal` takes place it becomes `-23.3333333333333M`.

I thought `decimal`s could hold bigger values and were hence more accurate so how am I losing data going from `double` to `decimal`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is by design. Quoting from the documentation of [`Convert.ToDecimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/a69w9ca0(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx) value returned by this method contains a maximum of
>   15 significant digits. If the *value* parameter contains more than 15
>   significant digits, it is rounded using rounding to nearest. The
>   following example illustrates how the Convert.ToDecimal(Double) method
>   uses rounding to nearest to return a [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx) value with 15
>   significant digits.
>
> ```
> Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(123456789012345500.12D));  // Displays 123456789012346000
> Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(123456789012346500.12D));  // Displays 123456789012346000
>
> Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(10030.12345678905D));      // Displays 10030.123456789 
> Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(10030.12345678915D));      // Displays 10030.1234567892
> ```

The reason for this is mostly that `double` can only guarantee 15 decimal digits of precision, anyway. Everything that's displayed after them (converted to a string it's 17 digits because that's what `double` uses internally and because that's the number you might need to exactly reconstruct every possible `double` value from a string) is not guaranteed to be part of the exact value being represented. So `Convert` takes the only sensible route and rounds them away. After all, if you have a type that can represent decimal values exactly, you wouldn't want to start with digits that are inaccurate.

So you're not losing *data*, per se. In fact, you're only losing garbage. Garbage you thought of being data.

**EDIT:** To clarify my point from the comments: Conversions between different numeric data types may incur a loss of precision. This is especially the case between `double` and `decimal` because both types are capable of representing values the other type cannot represent. Furthermore, both `double` and `decimal` have fairly specific use cases they're intended for, which is also evident from the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The Double value type represents a double-precision 64-bit number with
>   values ranging from negative 1.79769313486232e308 to positive
>   1.79769313486232e308, as well as positive or negative zero, PositiveInfinity, NegativeInfinity, and not a number (NaN). **It is
>   intended to represent values that are extremely large (such as
>   distances between planets or galaxies) or extremely small (the
>   molecular mass of a substance in kilograms) and that often are
>   imprecise (such as the distance from earth to another solar system).**
>   The Double type complies with the IEC 60559:1989 (IEEE 754) standard
>   for binary floating-point arithmetic.
>
> The Decimal value type represents decimal numbers ranging from
>   positive 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 to negative
>   79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335. **The Decimal value type is
>   appropriate for financial calculations that require large numbers of
>   significant integral and fractional digits and no round-off errors.**
>   The Decimal type does not eliminate the need for rounding. Rather, it
>   minimizes errors due to rounding.

This basically means that for quantities that will not grow unreasonably large and you need an accurate *decimal* representation, you should use `decimal` (sounds fairly obvious when written that way). In practice this most often means financial calculations, as the documentation already states.

On the other hand, in the vast majority of other cases, `double` is the right way to go and *usually* does not hurt as a default choice (languages like Lua and JavaScript get away just fine with `double` being the *only* numeric data type).

In your specific case, since you mentioned in the comments that those are temperature readings, it is very, very, *very* simple: Just use `double` throughout. You have *temperature readings.* Wikipedia suggests that highly-specialized thermometers reach around 10<sup>−3</sup> °C precision. Which basically means that the differences in value of around 10<sup>−13</sup> (!) you are worried about here are simply irrelevant. Your thermometer gives you (let's be generous) five accurate digits here and you worry about the ten digits of random garbage that come after that. Just don't.

I'm sure a physicist or other scientist might be able to chime in here with proper handling of measurements and their precision, but we were taught in school that it's utter bullshit to even give values more precise than the measurements are. And calculations potentially affect (and reduce) that precision.

Comment: This was existing code. Are we saying we'd be better off having decimal as the parent type and not converting down to double to do our conversions? Basically the problem we are having is when we grab this value to then convert back at a later date, the resulting conversion is out slightly. For instance -10 degrees fahrenheit becomes -9.99

Comment: If you start with `decimal` initially, convert to `double` somewhere and convert back to `decimal` afterwards, you may lose precision, yes. But there's a bit more to that, both `decimal` and `double` have very specific use cases that have not that much overlap, so code that uses *both* types for some reason can be considered suspect anyway.

Comment: As for the use cases: `double`: »It is intended to represent values that are extremely large (such as distances between planets or galaxies) or extremely small (the molecular mass of a substance in kilograms) and that often are imprecise (such as the distance from earth to another solar system)«, `decimal`: »The Decimal value type is appropriate for financial calculations that require large numbers of significant integral and fractional digits and no round-off errors. The Decimal type does not eliminate the need for rounding. Rather, it minimizes errors due to rounding.« (from the docs)

Comment: That is most likely given some of this code base! So ideally we be working with decimals only for our temperature readings?

Comment: You have temperature readings that are so precise that they exceed 15 digits of precision? I'd say that's unlikely. As a rule of thumb for using those types I'd say for anything monetary use `decimal`, for anything physics-based use `double`.